# Converting List<BaseType> to List<DerivedType> with performance in mind

Tags: c#, inheritance, generic-list

I have quite an intensive routine I am client of that returns a `List<BaseType>` to me. The routine has, among other parameters, a `DateTime`, but the returned `List<BaseType>` doesn't incorporate this information : `BaseType` doesn't have a `DateTime` member that could track this info. (This is because the routine was designed to be called on one date only, loops on many dates being done in VBA.)

Now I need to have this additional date info because I want to concatenate many different `List<BaseType>` (produced with different dates) in one `List<BaseType>` to which I want to apply some treatment needing to be date-aware.

So I implemented a straightforward class `DerivedType` deriving from `BaseType` and incorporating this date time additional info.

I would like to know what is the optimal (in terms of performance, ideally without copy) way to "convert" a `List<BaseType>` to `List<DerivedType>` where all `DerivedType` will have `DateTime` member with the same value.

*Remark.* I have in mind to concurrently put all produced `List<DerivedType>`'s in one `List<DerivedType>` that I will have to trim using `List`'s operations. This I why I want to stick to `List`'s.

**CLARIFICATION EDIT**

Context : In VBA I loop over many dates, for each date I produce an array thanks to a `c#` dll, and at the end, I print (in VBA) all these array somewhere. The production of one array in c# uses the aforementioned routine (I cannot change as it relies on a legacy dll) : a `List<BaseType>` is produced thx to a date, and treated in a date-dependent way to produce an array. What I want to do, is to remove the loop over dates from the VBA and to do it in c#. As the "treatment" really depends on the list nature of `List<BaseType>` and on the date, would `BaseType` incorporate the date info, I could concatenate all `List<BaseType>`'s to a unique `List<BaseType>` to which I would apply the treatment, instead of applying it list by list. But `BaseType` does not incorporate the date info so I am stuck ... This led to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do this because `List<T>` allows code to both add items to the list as well as extract items from the list. If you were to pretend the list only contained objects of the derived types, code that extracted an item might get the base type or *any other type descending from that base type*, which would *not* be that derived type. You have no option but to do a conversion, getting a new collection object.

Comment: Damien is right, its very unclear what you want. To cast the elements of a List in another Type, just use `List.Cast<T>()`.

Comment: To get a new list with only those objects that are of type `DerivedType`, use `list.OfType<DerivedType>().ToList()`

Comment: If all your objects have the same `DateTime` information use `DateTime time = baseTypeList.OfType<DerivedType>.First().DateTimeProperty;`. Now you don't need to convert the other objects because you don't need to know more.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is once I have produced a `baseTypeList` in a optimal way

Comment: Given update - are you sure you need to derive a new type? Could you not just pass all of your `BaseType`s into a `List<Tuple<BaseType,DateTime>>`? (Or `ValueTuple` or moral equivalents in modern C#)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes because to pass all of `BaseType`s into a `List<Tuple<BaseType,DateTime>>` I would have to iterate over the `List<BaseType>` which I especially want to avoid : I will create many lists that I will concatenate concurrently, and I will loop one time on this final big list.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj: why you need to have one `DateTime` per `BaseType` instance at all if all have the same DateTime-value? You just need a single parameter for your method

Comment: I don't think you can avoid iteration if you want to transform the objects. And there's no build in mechanism to transform the actual types of objects - so I was just suggesting a cheaper transformation.

Comment: If you don't need different DateTimes for your BaseClass you can always just write an extension method for BaseClass that returns whatever your DateTime is without deriving.

Comment: @ALL : I added a clarification bit to the question, explaining the context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative without casting. You still need to deal with list of list of lists though...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class BaseClass
    {
    }

    public class BaseClassList : List<BaseClass>
    {
        public DateTime CallDate { get; set; }

        public BaseClassList(IEnumerable<BaseClass> elements, DateTime CallDate)
            : base(elements)
        {
            this.CallDate = CallDate;
        }
    }

    public static class BaseClassExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime Date(this BaseClass ext, BaseClassList bcl)
        {
            return bcl.CallDate;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static List<BaseClass> Func(DateTime d)
        {
            BaseClass A = new BaseClass();
            BaseClass B = new BaseClass();
            return new List<BaseClass>() { A, B };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2017, 5, 1);
            DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2018, 5, 1);
            List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>() { d1, d2 };


            List<BaseClassList> myList = new List<BaseClassList>();

            foreach (DateTime d in dates)
                myList.Add(new BaseClassList(Func(d), d));

            foreach(var el in myList)
                foreach (BaseClass bc in el)
                    Console.WriteLine(bc.Date(el));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really need lists as explained